# blogger showing the whole post on homepage instead of thumbnail and title

Tags: javascript, html, templates, blogger, blogspot

Ok so I'm making a custom blogger template.  I know concepts like data tags and basic structure of blogger. But, since
I'm new at programming I am having some difficulties with this specific widget "blog post".
I know this is the most important widget but it's kinda difficult for me to edit this one because i don't know
what to change or what should i look for.
The problem here is whenever I apply this code, instead of showing thumbnail and title of the post it just shows whole post on my homepage.

The homepage looks fine before publishing anything but as soon as I publish a post it disappears leaving a disorientate page.

So please tell me if you guys know what type of specific code I need to change or do i have to write it from scratch in order to show only thumbnail and title of the post.

Here you can see the widget code: https://github.com/Blayke01/blogger/blob/master/blogger.html

Comment: Blayke, welcome to SO. show us your code which you are using now.

Comment: I can't share the whole code because it kinda lengthy and since I don't have level 10 I can't upload pic but it's a custom blogger code and if you paste the code given below inside blogger(edit html section) you can see the whole code.                                                                 <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='yes'>
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog' version='1'/>
</b:section>

Comment: @Blayke, It would be really great if you could atleast share any link to that page or any image (probably upload it somewhere else and share that here) for sake of getting the better responses. Let us know if that is feasible for you.

Comment: I also added widget code that I'm using you can check it on github